# Add Four Values in Different Activities in Android Application

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android. I have four stages (four activities). In activity one when you click on a button you have to store value. For example `counter1=3`. Every stage is like stage one. I am wondering if you can tell me how can I add these integer values together  and show up.

I want to add: counter1+counter2+counter3+counter4=score

How can I join these stages together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your count on using the intent extras. Below is an example of how to keep an incrementing count, but you could just pass them on from each activity and add them up at the end.

Activity 1

```
int count = 5;
```

navigating Activity 1 - Activity2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("counter", count);
```

Activity2

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("counter", 0);

count += 3; // count is 8
```

navigating Activity2 - Activity 3

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
intent.putExtra("counter", count);
```

Activity3

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("counter", 0);

count += 2; // count is 10
```

navigating Activity 3 - Activity 4

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity4.class);
intent.putExtra("counter", count);
```

Activity 4

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("counter", 0);

count += 1;

Log.i("TAG", "Your count is:"+count); // 11
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use button to get value and also I use list view to show my stages. I couldn’t run it. I think when I choose one stage for example stage1 and back to menu to choose another one for example stage 2 the score become zero like the first time when I open the activity.
How can I solve this problem .

Comment: If your using the back button. You will have to store the counter in SharedPreferences for persistance, or look at startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() with your one activity.

Comment: so, do you have any useful and easy toturial to understand how SharedPreferences or start ActivityForResult work?--->Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Send the value to next Activity like following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then on the receiving `NextActivity`, read value like following:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int receivedValue = extras.getString("key");
```

Now you can add the value from this activity and pass it to next one.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("counter", value); 
startActivity(intent);  I have to change key to counter1? I get value from button.I have to use this code in onclickListener of button?

Comment: Yes. you can do: myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){//put codes to startActivity here});

Answer (score 0):

Pass value as part of Bundle from one activity to another. In each activity add the value you want to and store it Bundle again and pass to next activity. See this link on how to use [Bundle](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html) to pass data between activites.

Comment: As I am beginner how can I do this?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to example.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(stagel.this, totalScore.class);Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putInt("counter", counter);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

Comment: In your other activity, you can access the bundle that was passed.. It's nuts easy.